# Regex generate exceptionwith unescaped string

Tags: c#, regex, exception, escaping

I'm trying to make a simple program to validate a string against a regular expression, but I'm getting an exception. Here is my code:

```
String exp = "^\\d\\d*$";
Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Unescape(exp));
if (r.IsMatch(""))
{
    Response.Write("strings matches");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("strings does not matches");
}
```

but this code generates the exception:

```
exception.Message = "parsing \"^\\d\\d*$\" - Unrecognized escape sequence \\d."

exception.GetType() ={Name = "ArgumentException" FullName = "System.ArgumentException"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Use @ to make the strings no longer use the escape character \ like this `String exp = @"^\\d\\d*$";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly, what the documentation to [Regex.Unescape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is saying. It throws an Argument exception, when it comes to an escape sequence that it cannot convert, like `\d`.

The `Regex.Unescape` methods converts string escape sequences with the appropriate characters itself, e.g.  `\n` with `0x0A`.

**You don't need to use the `Regex.Unescape` method here.**

```
String exp = "^\\d\\d*$";
Regex r = new Regex(exp);
```

is just fine.

Or the verbatim version:

```
String exp = @"^\d\d*$";
Regex r = new Regex(exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@` to make the strings not use the escape character `\` like this

`String exp = @"^\\d\\d*$";`